# Is it possible to use Gnome Shell 3.6 with 12.04?

Tags: gnome

I managed to get stuck on Gnome Shell 3.5.4. I want to get to 3.6 so that I can get my extensions back. I can't seem to find an answer on whether I MUST go to 12.10. I'd prefer to not do a version upgrade yet.

How would I get to 3.6 (or higher)? or am I stuck with 3.5.4?

Comment: If you used both the ricotz-testing Gnome PPA and the Gnome 3 Team PPA you should have 3.6

Comment: @UriHerrera so it seems that one can truly have 3.6 w/12.04. Yes? I had add the ricotz-testing ppa done initially, but was showing 3.5.4 after install. I then tried to go back to 3.4 and tried purging the PPAs.

I eventually added back Gnome-team PPA, but not the ricotz ppa (ppa:ricotz/testing). I see Gnome-team, but don't see ricotz-testing in my sources (via synaptic or software center); however, the file ricotz-testing-precise.list exists in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: @UriHerrera I added back in ricotz-testing PPA and still have 3.5.4. I can verify that it is my sources, along with gnome-team.